# string.equals() returns wrong value?

Tags: java, android

```
if (resEntity != null)  {
    res=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
    Log.i("RESPONSE",res);
}

xc=res.equals("true");
Log.i("xc",String.valueOf(xc));

if(xc) {
    Log.i("Yes","1");
}
else {
    Log.i("no","0");
}
```

above is my code in which i am sending a post request to our company server for checking a file it returns true if the file exists.I am providing my logcat.

```
09-24 11:20:19.570: I/url for checking update(3050): http://www.digitalmarketingbox.com/webtool/playerupdate.php
09-24 11:20:33.789: I/RESPONSE(3050): true
     09-24 11:20:33.789: I/xc(3050): false
```

as you can see,the response returned from server is true and i am also comparing it to true,so why equals() function is returning false ,please help me,or am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Is there possibly any whitespace following the response?

Comment: Please fix your indentation and blank lines when posting code - this code is far harder to read than it should be.

Comment: What do you get if you log `res.length()`?

Comment: What does your `EntityUtils.toString(resEntity)` return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most likely problem is whitespace in `res`. Try this:

```
res=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
```

Comment: ok this worked i will accept this answer thank you so much can you explain me in short what trim does

Comment: Check the API of [String.trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)

Comment: @newkid - `trim()` removes all leading and trailing whitespace in a string and returns the result as a new string.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are getting the `boolean` response and you trying to compare it using the String `equals()` method, which is not the correct way of doing it.

**EDIT:** As res is actually a string value so you need to make sure that it actually contains "true" without any extra spaces around.

Comment: Considering `res` is gotten from a `toString` call, it's hard to see how `res` is a boolean here.

Comment: yes and it is returning true,in my logcat you can check the value of RESPONSE tag for res,it is returning true

Comment: @newkid have u tried to use trim on res before checking like if "true".equals(res.trim()); ?

Answer (score 0):

Ya mey be you have space that why result is not in your favour So use trim to remove the space and then use like tha

```
    xc=res.trim().equals("true");
 if(xc)
        {
        Log.i("Yes","1");
         }
        else
        {
          Log.i("no","0");

        }
```

Comment: There's no comparison in that statement; it's an assignment.

Comment: xc is boolean res and "true" are Strings. Everybody is giving the same answer but I think this is incorrect.

Comment: @newkid no where in the question  u have mentioned that xc is boolean.So u better go and read ur question carefully first

Answer (score -1):

You can check like this.

```
 if(res.equals("true")
 {
     Log.i("Yes","1");
 }
 else
 {
     Log.i("No","0");
 }
```

Comment: How is that going to produce anything different?

Comment: it is not any different and i tried this before also and the control goes to else but the if block should be executed

Comment: Result is getting in that "res"..With that itself, can check the condition instead of converting into Boolean as he did in his code.

Comment: If you try this code, can u pls print what is the value you are getting in res